# Trouble uploading .xml file via PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to create a form where a user can upload an xml file to my server which will overwrite one that already exists. I'm using the code below (which I know doesn't upload the file if it already exists, but I'll fix that once I've fixed this).

The problem is that the first if statement fails at this statement

```
($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/xml")
```

meaning that I get an invalid file message. If I comment that out, the file uploads.

Changing the file types allowed to another type (eg jpg) works.

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("xml");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/xml"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 5000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("xml/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "xml/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "xml/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

I'm very new to PHP so be gentle, I have looked for similar questions but not found anything that seems to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: See what values you are getting in `$_FILES` variable by using `print_r` and then compare with your `if condition` whether its matching or not.

Comment: Thanks, using print_r showed it was showing as xml. Have changed the code to check the file name as whole against what I want it to be and that works. Not terribly secure I know, but for what I'm implementing it's fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP website:

$_FILES['userfile']['type']

```
The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information. An example would be "image/gif". This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.
```

"if the browser provided this information." some browser don't send type. You need validate via extension or parse XML.

Check this.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with

```
($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/xml")
```

Comment: You must explain what you are doing here. An answer is not a single line of code... What's the difference between `app.../xml` and `text/xml`. Provide references.